# How to fix a voltage drop on car power door lock

Tags: locks, voltage, central-locking

I've installed a Keetec car power door lock on my car. It works on four doors but even though it locks and unlocks the voltage on the actuators drops to about 7-8V. Problem is that the control unit for the fifth door requires 12V signal from the actuators to determine if the car is locked or not so the fifth door could not be opened if the car is locked. I've tried to lubricated the locks but that didn't helped. Do you have any ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Would there be any way to provide direct power from the battery by using a relay on the 5th door?

Comment: I have a power line going from the batery directly to the control unit so i can use it to provide power to a relay too but i've alredy tried to use a MOSFET instead of the relay (i don't have one at the moment) and it didn't work.

Comment: You might also consider using a 12v capacitor in some way. Just a thought.

Comment: Use as relay for each door lock; this lessens the total load on the controller... especially sensible for aftermarket things (usually made as cheap as possible...)